# unable to set name for route53 healthcheck entry

Tags: amazon-route53

this is how im setting up the entry

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/route53-healthcheck.json
{
  "IPAddress": "10.10.10.10",
  "Port": 80,
  "Type": "HTTP",
  "ResourcePath": "/somefile.txt"
}
EOF
aws route53 create-health-check \
    --caller-reference $(date +'%Y%m%dT%H%M%d') \
    --health-check-config file:///tmp/route53-healthcheck.json > /tmp/route53-healthcheck.log
```

and when i see the `route53` entry, its missing the name (the first entry is a manual entry and the second one is from the snippet above. Im referring to the red smudge.)
[image: missing name]

All the options listed in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-health-check.html) are not relevant.

```
{
  "IPAddress": "string",
  "Port": integer,
  "Type": "HTTP"|"HTTPS"|"HTTP_STR_MATCH"|"HTTPS_STR_MATCH"|"TCP"|"CALCULATED",
  "ResourcePath": "string",
  "FullyQualifiedDomainName": "string",
  "SearchString": "string",
  "RequestInterval": integer,
  "FailureThreshold": integer,
  "MeasureLatency": true|false,
  "Inverted": true|false,
  "HealthThreshold": integer,
  "ChildHealthChecks": ["string", ...]
}
```

Any ideas if there is another way to set the name of that in another way ?

## Solution

```
aws route53 change-tags-for-resource --resource-type healthcheck --resource-id 41633bb1-4adc-4357-983f-767191ff3248 --add-tags Key=Name,Value="new-name"
```

Some mistakes i made:

- my aws version was old. On ubuntu, i had to `apt-get remove awscli` and then install the latest version from pip with `pip install awscli`. Then the executable can be found in `~/.local/bin/aws`
- When i changed the name, i had to force reload the webpage instead of just refresh it with the aws icon (think `Ctrl+Shift+R`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the change-tags-for-resource CLI option to set a tag on a resource[1].

Example:

```
aws route53 change-tags-for-resource --resource-type healthcheck --resource-id <healthcheck guid> --add-tags Key=Name;Value=Value
```

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-tags-for-resource.html

Comment: Yes, the "Name" as we see it for AWS resources (be it an EC2 instance or a health check) is just a "Name" tag.

Comment: that worked with `--resource-id` instead of `--resource`

Comment: How can we retrieve a health check using name then (other than iterating over the list of health checks and identifying the one)