# How to add name to route 53 health check created using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

This code creates health check but does not have a name associated with it . I am not able to locate anything or in boto docs where we can specify name parameter while creating health checks. There are methods for specifying port,ip add,fqdn etc but not name.

Code snippet:

```
 health_check = boto.route53.healthcheck.HealthCheck(sys.argv[1],80,'HTTP','/',request_interval=30,failure_threshold=3)
 health_check = conn.create_health_check(health_check,caller_ref=sys.argv[2])['CreateHealthCheckResponse']['HealthCheck']
 hc_id = health_check['Id']
```

Comment: Which `name` are you trying to reference?

Comment: When i create the health check the name is not added,its blank i can refer the health check by using only its ID. No actually fqdn is different its needed if i want to monitor a URL/instance by name but here i want the IP to be monitored.

Comment: AFAIK you can only reference HealthCheck by ID (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_GetHealthCheck.html)

Comment: Yes but there must be some way by which name should be created as when we create health check from UI the first thing it asks is name but while creating it using boto script it creates blank health check. Actually i need name when i want to associate this health check with a route53 record.

Comment: The way they are created with the AWS API is through TAGS and creating the tag `name` (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeTagsForResource.html). But I can't see a means of updating tags through the boto API. Note: Boto3 has `change_tags_for_resource` (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html) which is what you are looking for - you could consider porting to Boto3 now that it is stable

Comment: FYI: Here's a stackoverflow question that talks about naming healthchecks using the AWS API/CLI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630269/unable-to-set-name-for-route53-healthcheck-entry

Comment: Thanks.. yes this is what i exactly want but i have a lot of other code also. It would not be easy to port everything to boto3. Is there any other way this could be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked 7 years ago and I am not sure how boto looks like back to the time. Let me provide the way it works in 2023.

In [create_health_check](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53/client/create_health_check.html), it do not take tags, therefore the workaround is to use both create_health_check and [change_tags_for_resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53/client/change_tags_for_resource.html), to create health check then tag it with the name you want.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('route53')

response = client.create_health_check(
  CallerReference=...,
  HealthCheckConfig={...}
)

health_check_id = response['HealthCheck']['Id']

client.change_tags_for_resource(
    ResourceType='healthcheck',
    ResourceId=health_check_id,
    AddTags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': ...
        },
        {
            'Key': 'environment',
            'Value': ...
        }
    ]
)
```

Replace the "..." with your own settings